# Django: Delete View with Javascript Confirmation without redirecting to Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-csrf

I have a a template where I can delete using Django DeleteView. I want it the data to be deleted after using the Javascript popup.

**Views.py**

```
class ObjectNameDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = ObjectName
    form_class = PostObjectName   
    success_url = 'http://localhost:8000/impact/displayobjects/'
```

**DisplayObjects.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'person_delete' obj.pk %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<a href="{% url 'person_delete' obj.pk %}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="deleteFunction()">Delete</button></a>
</form>

<script>
        function deleteFunction(e) {
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
                e.preventDefault();
            }            
        }
</script>
```

After I click the Delete button, there is an error:

**CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.**

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `type='submit'` from the buton

add class or id to the form and then in the `js` add 
`$('#your-form-id').submit();`

```
<form id='person-delete' method="POST" action="{% url 'person_delete' obj.pk %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<a href="{% url 'person_delete' obj.pk %}">
<button  class="btn btn-danger" onClick="deleteFunction()">Delete</button></a>
</form>


 function deleteFunction(e) {
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
                e.preventDefault();
            }else{
             $('#person-delete').submit();
            }            
        }
```

Your view is a class you have to add  `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)` before your logic in your `ObjectNameDeleteView()`

```
class ObjectNameDeleteView(View):
       @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
       #then your logic
```

Comment: It still shows error: "403 Forbidden CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Comment: Url('^person_delete/(?P<obj_pk>\d+)/$', views.personDelete, 'person_delete')  is that how your url looks like?

Comment: Is it a class or a def based view?

Comment: path('objects/delete/<int:pk>/', views.ObjectNameDeleteView.as_view(), name='person_delete')

Comment: Well that means it is a class view in this case put `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)` in your ObjectNameDeleteView
`class ObjectNameDeleteView(View):
  @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)`

Comment: I added the @csrf_exempt to the urls.py and it worked Thanks `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt path('objects/delete/<int:pk>/', csrf_exempt(views.ObjectNameDeleteView.as_view()), name='person_delete'),`

Comment: Glad to hear mate :)